# How to trigger debugging with Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to navigate to a URL where a web api exists? My efforts suggest no, common sense says it should be. Thus, I guess I have a fault else where.

I've started VS 2015, added a new project (ASP.NET) and chose web api. I have created my api

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public void Index()
    {
        //logic with break points set
    }
}
```

I also created a 'normal' MVC controller and as such, when I start the project, my web browser shows me the Index file in my Home controller.

Now, I want to navigate to the associated URL of my web api
The URL I have for my Home controller (Index view) is

```
http://localhost:61895/
```

Therefore my api should be (I think)

```
http://localhost:61895/api/default/
```

but I see the following in the browser

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

And my WebApiConfig is

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**edit**

I also tried  `localhost:61895/api/Default/Index` but the same issue

How do I debug my API in Visual Studio

Comment: I think you may be looking for http://localhost:61895/api/Default/Index as the URL.

Comment: Sadly not @MartinNoreke :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Web Api works on the routing is different to Mvc Controller.

There is no action part in web api.

The http action have to match the Beginning of the Action or the Attribute. For Example:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public void GetIndex()
    {
        //logic with break points set
    }
}
```

or

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Index()
    {
        //logic with break points set
    }
}
```

The the url will be

localhost:61895/api/Default

There is a good example at asp.net:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

[image]

## edit

add some screen shot.
I create a new web api project, and create new controller default:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public void GetIndex()
    {
        var a = "a";
    }
}
```

Then my url:

http://localhost:4349/api/default

as you can see the break point get hit.

[image: break point hit]

As per discussion in comments, the issue was the Global.asax.cs file

The order matters, and must in the following order

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

has to be before

`RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

Comment: So, how do I debug the code in visual studio? +1 as this is clear :)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Put the break point in the begging of GetIndex() method (like you would do in any other application), and run VS in debug mode. Then navigate to the url, then it should stop at the break point

Comment: I added the extra GetIndex and added the [HttpGet] to my original Index method - I then navigate to  `localhost:61895/api/Default` - it doesn't help

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions you dont need both. just either one with  [HttpGet]  or one called GetIndex

Comment: I tried with [HttpGet] and my original Index, and then I removed this and tried only with GetIndex (and no attribute). Same issue

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have edited the answer to include a test screen shot.
See if it help.

Comment: Sorry, the point is, I can see what you've done and understand it works for you. I have the same controller - yet, when navigating to the URL I'm presented with a "The resource cannot be found..." message :(

Comment: If you hve the time, can you please add a 'normal' controller (such as Home and the associated Index), test it still works?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions can you try create a new web project, and chose webapi type. And then create the DefaultController and try if it works. If it does, try compare with your current project. The reason I post what I tried is to give you something to compare in case if something was missing.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions ther is a normal HomeController in my project, it came with the default template and both the mvc page and api worked

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I just mailed my solution to you. the email subject is: `SO How to trigger debugging with Web Api - soultion`. I removed all the nuget package but you should be able to get it once you build the project. Just run it and put break point in the DefaultController/GetIndex method

Comment: The fault was actually... the Global.asax.cs. I had the exact same code, the difference was the order. Try cutting  `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` and making it the last line of code int eh Application_Start function and hopefully you'll see the error. Can you update your post with informatin, then I can mark as answered :D

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have add the ordering part, see if my description had any problem or not. Thanks

Comment: Thank you again for taking so much time with me on this!

Comment: does it matter that im not using MVC? i do not have the routing file in my project

Comment: @Gonzalo since this is really old answer, it may not fit to latest template/project.  It is possible that routing file is not there, which use the default. but since you did not mention what your problem is, I can not help

Comment: @AlanTsai i made a recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993969/asp-net-apicontroller-inside-a-webform-cant-reach-methods/54995063#54995063