# ASP.NET ApiController inside a webform can't reach methods

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I can't reach any methods from my ApiController in anyway, the routing does appear if i try to reach it by a browser but no methods are shown.

My Controller:

```
namespace AgroRiego.Controllers
{
    public class datacontrol : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("api/get")]
        public string Get([FromUri]string user, string pass)
        {
            string check = SQL.Reader("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + user + "' AND password='" + pass + "'");
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(check))
            {
                return "error en credenciales";
            }
            DataTable horarios = SQL.table_read("SELECT * FROM horario_riego");
            string json = Utils.ConvertDataTabletoJSON(horarios);

            return json;
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("api/post")]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            string i = value;
        }
    }
}
```

my global asax:

```
namespace AgroRiego
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

and my webapiconfig:

```
namespace AgroRiego
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configuración y servicios de API web

            // Rutas de API web
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

i have more webforms inside the project (originally it was just html pages with serverside code, but i need to add a couple methods to retrieve and send data, help much appreciated!

EDIT1: i managed to reach HTTP 200 changing the URL but i can't reach the methods anyway (in debug mode it does not stop on the breakpoints) how can i route correctly the Api (so it is not Login.aspx) and how do i fix the methods reaching?

[image: HTTP 200 but no method reached]

EDIT2: i read in documentation that i need this line in global:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

but im not using MVC does that matter? i tried reaching the routes with a brand new MVC Web Api and it yields "No Response"

Comment: just to clarify, are you trying to add web api handler to an exisiting asp .net web form project?

Comment: as a matter of fact i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a routerprefix with your controller. So you access the URL as

```
    http://localhost/routerprefix/router
```

HttpClient class can be use to send and receive HTTP requests and responses. Since you are trying to consume a WebApi from a aspx page, better way is to create a HttpClient instance

Below is a very simple implementation. Please check this url for further information

[MSDN sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:49342/api/get");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync();
    }
```

Comment: oh i see, i may have miswritten my question or being unclear as i do not want to consume the webapi from the aspx page, but rather create a separate webservice within the same project, does that make any sense? not english native im sorry

Comment: have you figured out anything?

Comment: I created a separate project with a SOAP (asmx) webservice in the end, but i do still want to know why this is an issue for future projects

Answer (score 1):

By the look of your set up, it seems correct

you have got:

1. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` - setup the attribute route
2. `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(` - setup the default route
3. `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` - to register at startup

so it should work.

I think the problem you are having is the way you are calling it

WebAPI routing work a little different to MVC

for example:

In you get method, the route is set as below

`[HttpGet, Route("api/get")]`

so you should call it `{host}/api/get` using a GET http method

in the screen shot, you are calling using `{host}/api/get/Get` - which would not have work, because no route would match

Same for your POST method

So give it another try and you should be able to reach it

Answer (score 0):

The URL to add in the rest testing tool is

```
http://localhost:49342/api/get
```

Method type is GET

If you are calling this web api from aspx page use the httpClient class.

Comment: i did try with that url but it yields "404", does that mean that the routing is off? can you elaborate more on the httpClient class? thanks a lot

Comment: Please check my new answer